# how to compare resources in android

Tags: android, resources

How can I compare two resources in android?

```
 if(newButton.getBackground()!=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.addbutton)){
        newButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deletebutton);

        }
        else{
            newButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.addbutton);

        }
```

I want to change the button background in each click..

Comment: Hope you had seen this type of button in android phones....add contact numbers...!"+"  "-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, findViewById returns View, not Drawable.

You can try `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.addbutton);`

I think your way is bad. In described situation you can save button state (id of background resource or something else) in its tag, and later analyze it in code. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Thanks for asking...nope..I am now working on its functionality...create new editText when clicked..!

Comment: korovyansk on twitter and korovyansk.blogspot.com (but it's mostly at russian language)

Comment: You can send me e-mail to korovyansk + gmail.com, I'll try to help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

newButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.newlist);
if(newList.getBackground()!=(findViewById(R.drawable.addbutton)).getBackground())
{
     newButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deletebutton);
}

Comment: thanks..but it will not make any sense...i want to check whether the background of the button is the same or not...if no I want it to be changed...!

Comment: Ok, try to compare resource ids.

Comment: getResources().getResourceName(resid)

Comment: but I want to get the current background of the button...then only I can decide whether to change it or not...!

Comment: "Current background of the button" - interesting. What is background? - xml file with few button states ( selected, pressed, ... ). Yes? Than you need to get current state of the button, and than you need get id of drawable that is related with current state. P.S. Sorry for my bad english, hope you understood my idea.